# How to display a set of text (<p>) when mouse hovers over a certain image?

Tags: html, image, css, hover

Ok, so let me describe the goal first. I am making a birthday page for my best friend. I asked some of her other close friends to give a message, birthday greeting, etc., for her which I will post/display on the website. My plan was to insert a picture of let's say "friend A". And then when viewing the webpage, when the viewer hovers over "friend A"'s picture, a corresponding "text box" (idk the correct term) appears over the picture of "friend A" containing that person's message for the celebrant. I want to implement this if possible, all in HTML5 and CSS3. I have totally no idea how to write the code for this task. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. If that task is possible, would the code also work if let's say, she views the page on a touchscreen device? Would the "text box" still appear if she touches the image of "friend A"?

Update: I was able to make it work through the comments below and through some other forums after I went hunting on Google. :) Anyways, so what I did was use an "image maker" to type the messages (now with even better fonts and emoticons) and then download that "image" as a .jpg file, and so now when I hover, another image appears over the original one. I have another question though, and I don't really know whether to start a new thread or not.

CSS

```
 .kristinapic {
    width : 300px;
    height: 400px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.kristina {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}
.kristina img {
    display: block;
}

.kristina .message {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 25px;


    }

.kristina:hover .message {
    opacity:3;
 }

.mikapic {
    width : 300px;
    height: 2000px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    float: center;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.mika {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 2000px;
}
.mika img {
    display: block;
}

.mika .mikamessage {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    width: 300px;
    height: 2000px;
    border-radius: 25px;


}

.mika:hover .mikamessage {
    opacity:3;
}

.mkpic {
    width : 300px;
    height: 400px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.mk {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}
.mk img {
    display: block;
}

.mk .message {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 25px;


}

.mk:hover .message {
    opacity:3;
}

.sineadpic {
    width : 300px;
    height: 400px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.sinead {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}
.sinead img {
    display: block;
}

 .sinead .message {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 25px;


}

.sinead:hover .message {
    opacity:3;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class ="kristina">
            <img src="mnh.jpg", class ="kristinapic" alt="" />
            <img src="kdc.jpg", class ="message" alt="" />
</div>

<div class ="mika">
            <img src="mnh.jpg", class ="mikapic" alt="" />
            <img src="mika.jpg", class ="mikamessage" alt="" />
</div>

<div class ="mk">
            <img src="mnh.jpg", class ="mkpic" alt="" />
            <img src="mk.jpg", class ="message" alt="" />
</div>

<div class ="sinead">
            <img src="mnh.jpg", class ="sineadpic" alt="" />
            <img src="sinead.jpg", class ="message" alt="" />
</div>
```

Anyways, how I want it to appear, is that the , since it is the "longest" image/block, that its contents are aligned to the center of the page or screen. Right now, it appears right below the first  and its contents, and above the last two  blocks. I have tried placing float: center ; , margin: center;, margin: auto; , to try to move it to the center, but it won't work. What should I do to do align the  and its contents to the center, or either the right (would also be fine) of the page?

Comment: Hey Carlos, generally if you want to use stack overflow you would have to try this at your own first. This is why your question was probably down voted. Most of the times people want to see that you have tried on your own and now have a real question that someone could answer.

Comment: Learn from these (http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/) and try it yourself, if still stuck paste code and we will help you with it

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for your advice! It's my first time here, I'll try to remember that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
   <img src="http://iconshow.me/media/images/ui/ios7-icons/png/512/person_1.png">
</div>
<p id="text">
   My message for you
</p>
```

CSS:

```
img{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
p{
   display: none;
}
div:hover + p{
   display: block;
}
```

Of course you would have to add the specific styling so your message actually shows not below but on top of the image. If you want to try this out, here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/patrickhaede/b9oot42k/).

Comment: Thanks for your advice and your help! I used that and some other info I found on Stackoverflow and other forums/tutorials online, and I was sort of able to make it work. :)

Comment: If this answer helped you though, you could mark it as correct, @CarlosMontemayor